# wine has to be removed before installing nvidia-331

Tags: drivers, nvidia, wine, playonlinux

I would try the method of this link [nvidia-libopencl1-331 has to be removed before installing WINE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449507/nvidia-libopencl1-331-has-to-be-removed-before-installing-wine)
But the Problem is i already have wine installed and so here is my problem.
I installed wine1.7 pepperlight and PlayOnLinux. The Problem would be i could delete these things and reinstall everything, but there should be an easier way.

Here my error:
        Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
        nvidia-libopencl1-331 : Kollidiert mit: libopencl1
                             Kollidiert mit: libopencl1:i386
        ocl-icd-libopencl1 : Kollidiert mit: libopencl1
        ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 : Kollidiert mit: libopencl1

Comment: have you tried this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/452782/46437)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [nvidia-libopencl1-331 has to be removed before installing WINE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449507/nvidia-libopencl1-331-has-to-be-removed-before-installing-wine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you may be out of luck. You could try temporarily disabling the driver, but the instructions work or bust. Sorry!

Comment: Ok. I am just trying to remove wine completely. First wine from ppa. Than wine normal and now i will try the instructions.

Comment: So actually. I did too much. First i removed wine. Than installed everything like in the instructions to see, that installing nvidia afterwards removes everything from before, so i will reinstall the instructions again, and hopefully it works...

Comment: Seems to work. So before installing nvidia-331 remove wine completly follow the instructions in the link above and you can finally install wine

Comment: Or you could have downloaded the DEB file from WineHQ.com. But it worked so whatevs