# Nvidia problem when installing wine

Tags: wine, nvidia-optimus

I have a system that has optimus Nvidia card, so when i try to install wine it says.

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates
```

I have tried wine1.6 & wine1.7 same they will remove it `nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates` and i will not be able to use Optimus.

Is there any work around to install wine ?

---

```
one@Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libavdevice53 libavfilter3 libswresample0 smplayer-translations
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  binfmt-support fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core fonts-wqy-microhei gnome-exe-thumbnailer icoutils libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libcapi20-3
  libcapi20-3:i386 libdb5.3:i386 libexif12:i386 libgd3:i386 libgif4:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port10:i386
  libgpm2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 liblcms2-2:i386
  libldap-2.4-2:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libncurses5:i386 libodbc1 libopenal1:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386
  libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386
  libv4lconvert0:i386 libvpx1:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libxpm4:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2
  p11-kit-modules:i386 p7zip ttf-wqy-microhei unixodbc wine-gecko2.24 wine-gecko2.24:i386 wine-mono4.5.2 wine1.7-amd64 wine1.7-i386:i386
  winetricks
Suggested packages:
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl libterm-readline-perl-perl isdnutils-doc isdnutils-doc:i386 libgd-tools:i386 gphoto2:i386 gtkam:i386 gpm:i386
  libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386 gstreamer-codec-install:i386 gnome-codec-install:i386 gstreamer0.10-tools:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386
  liblcms2-utils:i386 libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc unixodbc-bin libportaudio2:i386 libroar-compat2:i386 hplip:i386 hpoj:i386
  libsane-extras:i386 libsasl2-modules-otp:i386 libsasl2-modules-ldap:i386 libsasl2-modules-sql:i386 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit:i386
  libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal:i386 opencl-icd:i386 p7zip-full dosbox:any winbind
Recommended packages:
  wine1.5-amd64 wine1.5-i386:i386 unixodbc:i386 wine-mono4.5.2:i386 wine
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binfmt-support fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core fonts-wqy-microhei gnome-exe-thumbnailer icoutils libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libcapi20-3
  libcapi20-3:i386 libdb5.3:i386 libexif12:i386 libgd3:i386 libgif4:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port10:i386
  libgpm2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 liblcms2-2:i386
  libldap-2.4-2:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libncurses5:i386 libodbc1 libopenal1:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386
  libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386
  libv4lconvert0:i386 libvpx1:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libxpm4:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2
  p11-kit-modules:i386 p7zip ttf-wqy-microhei unixodbc wine-gecko2.24 wine-gecko2.24:i386 wine-mono4.5.2 wine1.7 wine1.7-amd64
  wine1.7-i386:i386 winetricks
0 upgraded, 61 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 166 MB of archives.
After this operation, 537 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

---

aptitude suggested by @Yuriy Nazarenko

```
sudo aptitude install wine1.7
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binfmt-support{a} fonts-horai-umefont{a} fonts-unfonts-core{a} fonts-wqy-microhei{a} gnome-exe-thumbnailer{a} icoutils{a} 
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} libcapi20-3{a} libcapi20-3:i386{a} libdb5.3:i386{a} libexif12:i386{a} libgd3:i386{a} libgif4:i386{a} 
  libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port10:i386{a} libgpm2:i386{a} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386{a} libgstreamer0.10-0:i386{a} libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} libieee1284-3:i386{a} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{a} 
  libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} libltdl7:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libncurses5:i386{a} libodbc1{a} libopenal1:i386{a} libosmesa6{a} 
  libosmesa6:i386{a} libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} libsane:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} 
  libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libvpx1:i386{a} libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a} 
  ocl-icd-libopencl1{ab} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{ab} odbcinst{a} odbcinst1debian2{a} p11-kit-modules:i386{a} p7zip{a} ttf-wqy-microhei{a} 
  unixodbc{a} wine-gecko2.24{a} wine-gecko2.24:i386{a} wine-mono4.5.2{a} wine1.7 wine1.7-amd64{a} wine1.7-i386:i386{a} winetricks{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 61 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 166 MB of archives. After unpacking 537 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates : Conflicts: libopencl1 which is a virtual package.
                                 Conflicts: libopencl1:i386 which is a virtual package.
 ocl-icd-libopencl1 : Conflicts: libopencl1 which is a virtual package.
 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 : Conflicts: libopencl1 which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:                               
1)     nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates                              

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                 
2)     nvidia-331-updates recommends nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Comment: File a bug report with the packager.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen This also didn't work for me http://askubuntu.com/questions/449507/nvidia-libopencl1-331-has-to-be-removed-before-installing-wine

Comment: The first answer to the question outlines the problem. I did not follow the links in the second answer, but again you need to file a bug report against the two packages.

Comment: @Qasim did you try only the accepted answer or did you also try AmanicA answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/449507/nvidia-libopencl1-331-has-to-be-removed-before-installing-wine

Comment: @ElderGeek Yes i did try the accepted answer ( if you check the question you will find its not working, no i didn't tried the other one )

Comment: Amanica answer is the better one. Please try it and let me know if it works for you! Thank you!

Comment: AmanicA's answer worked for me - I had an identical problem with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came upon the same problem last night when installing Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty), and this solution from [AmanicA](https://askubuntu.com/users/7166/amanica) worked for me (as also suggested by many others above).

My system has a Nvidia GeForce GT 750M card. Installing ocl-icd-opencl-dev will remove nvidia-libopencl1-*, but that does not cause any trouble to me so far. Please see the original post for more details and explanation of why this works: [nvidia-libopencl1-331 has to be removed before installing WINE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449507/nvidia-libopencl1-331-has-to-be-removed-before-installing-wine)

(I do not mean to duplicate the post but try to help more people find this solution.)

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit 
sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev 
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed wine *(execly named "wine", "q4wine" and "winetricks" packages)* and there were no problem with my nvidia 310 driver today. But, I suggest you to **try aptitude** *(not apt-get, maybe you have to install aptitude as me)* to install wine version you want. Of course, you'll get a conflict... but! you **may not accept** this by answering "no" and aptitude will search another way to resolve your conflict and the next question might be to update some packages (not delete).
And if conflicts are of outdated packages, you can **just update** your system and than try again install your wine ;)

Answer (score 0):

AmanicA might works in some cases, but not every time. Fails with nvidia-340 on Utopic for example.

The real issue is with the ocl-icd design policy to be fixed
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/1328542

so add your 'affect me too' to get more devs attention

Answer (score 0):

Not to be snide or superior, but I find that archlinux works very well with wine and the nvidia packages. Granted, I don't have an optimus capable GPU, so results may vary.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that you need to do.  Try fixing your software packing system.  Then test the various drivers that are provided by default in the repository.

Try using the procedure described here to fix the integrity of your packaging:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/461975/i-cant-edit-update-remove-or-install-my-broken-packages/461989#461989

Perform the loop of:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove && sudo apt-get autoclean
$ sudo apt-get -f install
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Until you don't get errors.  Address the errors them move to the next step described below.

Run "Additional Drivers" to install the best nVidia drivers.  If you don't have success with one try the other.