# To install Wine, remove graphics driver - wut?

Tags: graphics, wine, 14.10, radeon

I have been troubleshooting display problems (my computer was using default Ubuntu drivers and I finally managed to get the proprietary `fglrx-update` to work instead. I noticed that one of the `apt-get` actions was to remove Wine but I don't understand why that would be necessary.

Now that I've got my display working nicely, I thought I'd reinstall Wine (because I use an app that needs it). But **when I try to install Wine, aptitude wants to remove the graphics drivers I just finished installing!**

I don't believe I have to choose between a working display and Wine.
--> Can't I have both? How can I solve this dilemma?

```
torben@torben-desktop$ sudo aptitude install wine
[sudo] password for torben: 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ocl-icd-libopencl1{ab} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{ab} wine wine1.6{a} 
  wine1.6-amd64{a} wine1.6-i386:i386{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
Need to get 32,9 MB of archives. After unpacking 247 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx-updates-core : Conflicts: libopencl1 which is a virtual package.
                      Conflicts: libopencl1:i386 which is a virtual package.
 ocl-icd-libopencl1 : Conflicts: libopencl1 which is a virtual package.
 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 : Conflicts: libopencl1 which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:
1)     fglrx-amdcccle-updates      
2)     fglrx-updates               
3)     fglrx-updates-core          

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
Abandoning all efforts to resolve these dependencies.
Abort.
torben@torben-desktop$
```

Comment: Try removing the drivers, installing wine and then installing the drivers again.

Comment: I experience the same issue.

Comment: @PranavMarathe I spent _days_ getting the display to work and I'm worried I might not be able to get it right again - so I would _really_ prefer a solution that doesn't remove my graphics drivers. (Why is graphics support so damn hard in Linux??!)

Comment: because it forces people to use winblows.  which is what the current CEO's wish is.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun Looks like wine 1.7 doesn't have this issue. You can try installing that. If you need wine 1.6 then you'll have to compile it from it's source code and leave out the libopencl1 packages.

Comment: Thank you @PranavMarathe, I followed [these instructions](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) but still causes the `fglrx` drivers to be removed ([screenshot](http://pastebin.com/asWtC12X)) - I didn't go through with it.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun: If you're worried, that you bork your current configuration while trying new stuff, back it up. The minimal system configuration backup would be the content of `/etc` (pro-tip: use [`etckeeper`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/etckeeper/)) and the [package list](/a/99151).

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun The other option is to build wine from source but exclude the OpenCL libraries. You can find info on how to do that in this thread : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2257502

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun Also, I've found that if you use Ubuntu's `Additional Drivers` section (found under `Settings`) and install `fglrx` (and not `fglrx-update`) it installs fairly reliably.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun According to this [thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/472433/nvidia-problem-when-installing-wine), if you run `sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-opencl-dev` before installing wine, wine should install without problems. Refer to this [thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449507/nvidia-libopencl1-331-has-to-be-removed-before-installing-wine) for a more detailed explanation of why this happens.

Comment: There are more details available at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/+bug/1129409 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/540780/14-10-wine-and-fglrx-conflict/573556#573556

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to build wine without OpenCL

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2257502&p=13194027#post13194027

There is also an open bug you might consider voting for at:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.6/+bug/1405264

Comment: What a relief to learn about that bug! So it's not just me being dense, there really is a problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

remove that driver and use this guid to install the supported version

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

then install wine

Comment: I have followed this guide and my output of `fglrxinfo` gives the result indicated in the page (step 8). However, in `Settings > Details > Overview`, "Graphics" is still listed as "VESA: -100" -- not what I expected, even after installing hardware acceleration.

Comment: did you check for when you consider using the fglrx driver is whether your AMD graphics card is supported ?
if it's supported you have tot choose the installation methode 2 or 2.1 not the two of them !!
then choose 3.1 or 3.2 (i recommand 3.1)
then 4. Enabling Video Hardware Acceleration

Comment: Yes it is supported (good point). I was aware not to do both variants but I might have skipped some parts of chapter 3.1 so I am re-doing the guide now.