# NOUVEAU on 2013 15" macbook 14.04 crashes on resume

Tags: nvidia, suspend, macbook, nouveau

I have a 2013 Macbook Pro 15" (Macbook 11,3). My laptop works perfectly fine except awaking from suspend. I can see the screen, the keyboard does not work after waking up and my laptop (at least my mouse) freezes after 30 seconds after waking up.

Nvidia drivers work perfectly fine for suspend and resume. But the nvidia drivers have low resolution during bootup and my brigtness cannot be adjusted using nvidia drivers.

I am attaching the Xorg.0.log log file that has the error message with the crash of the driver.

My options:

1. (Preferred) identify why this is failing and fix the Nouveau driver.
2. Fix the Nvidia brightness issue (from googling this seems to be an easier fix, but I prefer to use the Nouveau driver)
3. Live with NVidia driver without adjusting my screen brightness (a little difficult situation)
4. Use Nouveau but shutdown my laptop every time instead of suspending. A very difficult situation to accept in today's world.

Comment: Couldn't find a way to attach files. sharing it in comment. 
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  200 events have been dropped.
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7f4d49d70c78]

[   202.700] [mi] Increasing EQ size to 1024 to prevent dropped events.
[   202.700] [mi] EQ processing has resumed after 241 dropped events.
[   202.701] [mi] This may be caused my a misbehaving driver monopolizing the server's resources.

Comment: use http://paste.ubuntu.com and add link to the question

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on a mbp 2009. Works fine with the NVidia driver, but I would prefer to use the Nouveau driver due to problems with the Nvidia driver with Wine.

Comment: I fixed my wine problems with the nvidia driver following recommendations in this post: http://askubuntu.com/a/452782/230067

Comment: Same problem, except the Nvidia drivers don't work at all for me. All I get is a garbled screen.