# Did wine installation delete part of my GPU driver?

Tags: wine, software-center

I was installing wine via USC, and it displayed this pop up window:

[image]

I hit install... (did I needed to uninstall manually that package) and then the display dimmed, and the System monitor showed that process is in Sleeping status.

I forced quit and restarted USC and wine was auto finishing installation. 
Now I wonder is that package uninstalled or not, did it delete part of my GPU driver etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same pop-up window yesterday, but fortunately I didn't proceed with the install. This is apparently a known issue, and an explanation is available at [nvidia-libopencl1-331 has to be removed before installing WINE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449507/nvidia-libopencl1-331-has-to-be-removed-before-installing-wine). That procedure goes a bit over my head, but I followed it anyway and I was able to install wine without messing up my Nvidia driver.