# Install PlayonLinux

Tags: drivers, nvidia, wine, playonlinux

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and enabled the nvidia drivers. Now I am trying to install PlayonLinux but I get the message:

```
nvidia-libopencl1-331 has to be removed before installing PlayonLinux
```

I see the post: [nvidia-libopencl1-331 has to be removed before installing WINE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449507/nvidia-libopencl1-331-has-to-be-removed-before-installing-wine)

But when i try to do this, appears: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libcogl15: Depends: libegl1-mesa-drivers
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver :: Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages (hold).
```

Comment: Anyone can help me???

Comment: Are there any held packages? What's the output of `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`