# Installing Wine, but Need to Remove Nvidia-opencl-304

Tags: nvidia, wine

I want to install a software that only support Windows platform. So, I think I need to install Wine first. But, in the beginning of installation I got a message to remove Nvidia-opencl-304 before to install Wine. I'm really an average user. I don't want to remove my Nvidia, because I remember when I just installed Ubuntu, I had overheating problem. Just after installing Nvidia 304, the problem was solved.

So, can someone suggest me something. If I want to stay with the plan to install Wine, what should I do? And, if there is another options not to install Wine, what then the other software that has the same function?

Update:

I've tried to install ocl-icd-opencl-dev by using this: sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit, but I got an error message. The detail can be seen on the picture:

[image]

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449507/nvidia-libopencl1-331-has-to-be-removed-before-installing-wine does the solution there work for you?

Comment: It didn't work. The detail is on the edited question above.

Comment: In case you don't need Open CL, and running a Wine version through PlayonLinux does not work for you, you can also run Wine without it. That is, remove nvidia-opencl-304, then install Wine.

Comment: @herrysusanto: and feed-back on the last comment above?

Comment: I decided for not having Wine in my machine. I contacted the creator of the software that I want to install. Then they guide me how to install it on Linux. Much better for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to my [web-blog](http://xuancong84.blogspot.sg/2015/03/installing-conflicting-packages-on.html) to solve this issue.

I have just successfully installed both CUDA and Wine on my Ubuntu 14.04. And both of them are working.

Basically, you need to use aptitude to exam each conflict carefully and modify the right entries in /var/lib/dpkg/status so that the dependencies for installed packages get changed and they no longer cause conflict with new packages. After that, you can install new packages.